# t:selectOneRadio is not working in tomahawk version 2.0

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I am using http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/index.html and http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html.

I have used tomahawk `<t:selectOneRadio>` in my jsf page.

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="myScript" value="#{bean.myScript}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="Every" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="Every weekday" />
</t:selectOneRadio>

<t:radio for="myScript" index="0" />
<t:radio for="myScript" index="1" />
```

I am not able to view the radio buttons, where-in the same code worked properly in JSF 1.1 with the equivalent Tomahawk libraries in jboss6.

Comment: any ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: I think the bug is on itemLabel="". Try add something there to see it works, but in theory that code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should put what you want to show to the user in the itemLabel attribute, and a identifier in the itemValue

Like this

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="myScript" value="#{bean.myScript}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Every" itemValue="every" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Every weekday" itemValue="everyWeekday" />
</t:selectOneRadio>

<t:radio for="myScript" index="0" />
<t:radio for="myScript" index="1" />
```

Regards